# Why does \hfill work in math mode but not \vfill?

Tags: math-mode, sagetex, text-mode, hfill, vfill

This example writes three lines, each of which have four numbers separated by an equal length of space.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\thispagestyle{empty}%
1\hfill2\hfill3\hfill4\\5\hfill6\hfill7\hfill8\\9\hfill10\hfill11\hfill12
\end{document}
```

```
1 (SPACE) 2 (SPACE) 3 (SPACE) 4
5 (SPACE) 6 (SPACE) 7 (SPACE) 8
9 (SPACE) 10 (SPACE) 11 (SPACE) 12
```

The line of code operates normally under math mode.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\thispagestyle{empty}%
$1\hfill2\hfill3\hfill4\\5\hfill6\hfill7\hfill8\\9\hfill10\hfill11\hfill12$
\end{document}
```

```
1 (SPACE) 2 (SPACE) 3 (SPACE) 4
5 (SPACE) 6 (SPACE) 7 (SPACE) 8
9 (SPACE) 10 (SPACE) 11 (SPACE) 12
```

Now I want the three lines to be spread out across the page with equal spacing inbetween. However when I change the newlines to `\vfill` I get an error:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\thispagestyle{empty}%
$1\hfill2\hfill3\hfill4\vfill5\hfill6\hfill7\hfill8\vfill9\hfill10\hfill11\hfill12$
\end{document}
```

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 $1\hfill2\hfill3\hfill4\vfill
                                 5\hfill6\hfill7\hfill8\vfill9\hfill10\hfill...
```

Only when I put the `\vfill`s out of math mode will it compile:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\thispagestyle{empty}%
$1\hfill2\hfill3\hfill4$\vfill$5\hfill6\hfill7\hfill8$\vfill$9\hfill10\hfill11\hfill12$
\end{document}
```

```
1 (SPACE) 2 (SPACE) 3 (SPACE) 4
(SPACE)
5 (SPACE) 6 (SPACE) 7 (SPACE) 8
(SPACE)
9 (SPACE) 10 (SPACE) 11 (SPACE) 12
```

Using `amsmath`'s `\text` to force textmode did not help.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\thispagestyle{empty}%
$1\hfill2\hfill3\hfill4\text{\vfill}5\hfill6\hfill7\hfill8\text{\vfill}9\hfill10\hfill11\hfill12$
\end{document}
```

How come `\hfill` works fine in math mode while `\vfill` does not? Is there a workaround to make it usable in math mode? When typing manually I could just open and close math mode eveytime I need a `\vfill`, but when using `sagetex` the output is printed using `$\sagestr{some_custom_functions(some_variable)}$`, which means that everything the function outputs must be usable in mathmode.

Comment: "Missing $ inserted" mean that expect only `\vfill` **out** of the math mode, the same that if you try `$1\textbf{foo}2$` instead of  `$1$ \textbf{foo} $2$`.

Comment: vfill can not work in horizontal mode:  hbox, mbox, math, ...

Comment: @Fran `$1\textbf{foo}2$` is not an error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Opps, what bad  example!  I would be thinking about \paragraph or so... `:(`

Comment: Welcome, @zhsm54983

Answer (score 3):

`$` is inline math, which is why `vfill` won't work.

But you can also use an array to do something similar. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[\arraycolsep=10pt\def\arraystretch{3}
\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `arraycolsep` is your `hfill` and the `arraystretch` is your `vfill`. You can adjust these values as necessary.

[image]

You can also add extra vertical space to just one line by adding something like `[30pt]` after the line break in the array:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[\arraycolsep=10pt\def\arraystretch{3}
\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\[30pt]
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `\vfill` primitive inserts `\par` before it if it is in horizontal mode and it causes error in math mode. TeX suggests to close the math mode by inserting `$` and `\vfill` is "to be read again" as we can read in the error message.

You can insert your `\vfill` in the `\vadjust` parameter. This primitive waits to finishing the paragraph and then inserts the vertical material from its parameter between lines of created paragraph. Your example can look like this:

```
\noindent
$1\hfill2\hfill3\hfill4\vadjust{\vfill}\break
 5\hfill6\hfill7\hfill8\vadjust{\vfill}\break
 9\hfill10\hfill11\hfill12$
```

Answer (score 0):

`\vfill` is illegal in math mode, as you discovered. But you can use `\vspace{\fill}` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,showframe]{geometry}% for a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
$1\hfill2\hfill3\hfill4\vspace{\fill}\\
5\hfill6\hfill7\hfill8\vspace{\fill}\\
9\hfill10\hfill11\hfill12$

\end{document}
```

I used `a5paper` just to get a smaller picture and `showframe` for showing the boundaries of the text block.

[image]